# show returning wrong value when used with unsafeCoerced value

Tags: haskell, ghc, coercion

I was experimenting with `unsafeCoerce` with `Int8` and `Word8`, and I found some surprising behaviour (for me anyway).

`Word8` is a 8 bit unsigned number that ranges from 0-255. `Int8` is a signed 8 bit number that ranges from -128..127.

Since they are both 8 bit numbers, I assumed that coercing one to another would be safe, and just return the 8 bit values as if it was signed/unsigned.

For example, `unsafeCoerce (-1 :: Int8) :: Word8` I would expect to result in a `Word8` value of 255 (since the bit representation of -1 in a signed int is the same as 255 in an unsigned int).

However, when I do perform the coerce, the `Word8` the behaviour is strange:

```
> GHCi, version 7.4.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
> import Data.Int
> import Data.Word
> import Unsafe.Coerce
> class ShowType a where typeName :: a -> String
> instance ShowType Int8 where typeName _ = "Int8"
> instance ShowType Word8 where typeName _ = "Word8"

> let x = unsafeCoerce (-1 :: Int8) :: Word8
> show x
"-1"
> typeName x
"Word8"
> show (x + 0)
"255"
> :t x
x :: Word8
> :t (x + 0)
(x + 0) :: Word8
```

I don't understand how `show x` is returning `"-1"` here. If you look at `map show [minBound..maxBound :: Word8]`, no possible value for `Word8` results in `"-1"`. Also, how does adding 0 to the number change the behaviour, even if the type isn't changed? Strangely, it also appears it is only the `Show` class that is affected - my `ShowType` class returns the correct value.

Finally, the code `fromIntegral (-1 :: Int8) :: Word8` works as expected, and returns 255, and works correctly with `show`. Is/can this code be reduced to a no-op by the compiler?

Note that this question is just out of curiosity about how types are represented in ghc at a low level. I'm not actually using unsafeCoerce in my code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like @kosmikus said, both `Int8` and `Int16` are implemented using an `Int#`, which is 32 bit-wide on 32-bit architectures (and `Word8` and `Word16` are `Word#` under the hood). [This comment](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.2/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/GHC-Prim.html#g:1) in GHC.Prim explains this in more detail.

So let's find out why this implementation choice results in the behaviour you see:

```
> let x = unsafeCoerce (-1 :: Int8) :: Word8
> show x
"-1"
```

The `Show` instance for `Word8` [is defined as](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Word.html#Word8)

```
instance Show Word8 where
    showsPrec p x = showsPrec p (fromIntegral x :: Int)
```

and [`fromIntegral`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) is just `fromInteger . toInteger`. The definition of `toInteger` for `Word8` is

```
toInteger (W8# x#)            = smallInteger (word2Int# x#)
```

where `smallInteger` (defined in integer-gmp) is

```
smallInteger :: Int# -> Integer
smallInteger i = S# i
```

and `word2Int#` is a [primop](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/PrimOps) with type `Word# -> Int#` - an analog of `reinterpret_cast<int>` in C++. So that explains why you see `-1` in the first example: the value is just reinterpreted as a signed integer and printed out.

Now, why would adding `0` to `x` give you `255`? Looking at the `Num` instance for `Word8` we see this:

```
(W8# x#) + (W8# y#)    = W8# (narrow8Word# (x# `plusWord#` y#))
```

So it looks like the `narrow8Word#` primop is the culprit. Let's check:

```
> import GHC.Word
> import GHC.Prim
> case x of (W8# w) -> (W8# (narrow8Word# w))
255
```

Indeed it is. That explains why adding 0 is not a no-op - `Word8` addition actually clamps down the value to the intended range.

Comment: Thanks it makes perfect sense now!

Answer (score 4):

You can't say something is wrong when you've used `unsafeCoerce`.  Anything can happen if you use that function.  The compiler probably stores an `Int8` in a word, and using `unsafeCoerce` to `Word8` breaks the invariants on what is stored in this word.  Use `fromIntegral` to convert.

Conversion from `Int8` to `Word8` using `fromIntegral` turns into a `movzbl` instruction using ghc on x86, which is basically a no-op.

Comment: I understand that anything can happen, but I am interested to know what is happening under the hood. Unless a `Word8` consumes more than 1 byte when used in haskell, I can't figure out how you can get this behaviour with `unsafeCoerce`. `length [minBound..maxBound :: Word8]` is 256, the same number of combinations as in a byte. So how can there be any invalid values? Is there any way to dump the raw value of a value in haskell to see what is going on?

Comment: As Lennart says, an `Int8` is most likely stored in a word. For example, on a 64-bit machine I'm getting `"-1"` for `show (unsafeCoerce (-1 :: Int8) :: Word32)`, but `"18446744073709551615"` for `show (unsafeCoerce (-1 :: Int8) :: Word64)`.